# Migrating to OpenJDK from Oracle JDK

Tags: java

I am working on migrating my java application from Oracle JDK to adoptOpenJdk.So what changes would be required to migrate to AdoptOpenJdk.

Comment: Ever heard of write once, run anywhere?

Comment: I can't think of any reason you'd need to make *ANY* changes to your application.

Comment: But i have been asked to explore what changes would be required for migration.

Comment: Im afraid you will have to use the OpenJDK and see if all the libs/jars you are using are supported in the new OpenJDK. if not you will need to look for the equivalent

Comment: Can you please tell me what are the major diffrences between oracle jdk and AdoptOpenJdk?

Answer (score 2):

## Feature parity

Oracle has committed to keeping their *Oracle JDK* product at feature parity with the codebase in the *OpenJDK* project. So any Java app running on Oracle JDK should run on any other platform built faithfully from the OpenJDK codebase. **You need not make any changes** to your Java programming.

Be aware that OpenJDK only provides source code. For binaries and installers, you must look elsewhere. Several companies provide such binaries and installers. One of those is a joint venture known as *AdoptOpenJDK*. Others include Azul Systems, Red Hat/IBM, SAP, BellSoft, Amazon, Oracle, and Pivotal.

Most of the vendors, including Oracle, provide JVMs using the HotSpot optimizing compiler and runtime. AdoptOpenJDK (at least) offers you a choice to obtain a build using the *OpenJ9* optimizing runtime instead. Your Java app should run well on either HotSpot or OpenJ9, but you may see a different performance profile.

See [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59003120/642706) to a similar Question.

Be aware that the current licensing terms for the *Oracle JDK* product require that for use in production you must pay a fee. That product is free-of-cost only for non-production use such as development and testing. If you do not want to pay such a fee to Oracle, use their unsupported product at JDK.java.net, or use a JVM provided by one of the other vendors as shown in this flowchart.

[image]