# Is Wildfly 13.0.0.FINAL supports OpenJDK 8.0?

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

I am trying to update my application JDK-8 to OpenJDK 8.0 and also want to run OpenJDK 8.0 on wildfly 13.0.0.FINAL server, but Wildfly is not starting.

**What is the minimum OpenJDK version required for running wildfly 13.0.0 FINAL?**

Comment: The [Getting Started Guide](https://docs.wildfly.org/13/Getting_Started_Guide.html#requirements) says Java 8. And OpenJDK is a source only distribution. So you need to clarify exactly what you're trying.

Comment: I am  trying to upgrade oracle JDK to OpenJDK 8.0. after upgrading wildly server is not starting. What all changes i need to make when upgrading to OpenJDK 8.0 in order to start Wildfly?

Comment: will there any impact on wildfly If we use source only distribution?

Comment: **none**. What openjdk 8.0 have you "upgraded to"? Because that is not a release. OpenJDK provides **no** releases. You can't install it. And you can't run it. You would have to build it from source. You want to **install** (correctly) a **release** of OpenJDK 8. For example, [adoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/). How did you upgrade?

Comment: I copied the distribution folder into the current JDK folder and set the path in the system variable.

Comment: That is not how you install any JDK. And what "distribution folder"?

Answer (score 1):

**Wildfly 13 supports from any JDK (includes Oracle JDK, OpenJDK, AdoptedOpenJDK,..) version from 8 to 10.**

**Note :** OpenJDK supports only the source code. It doesn't provide installers and builds.

Better use **AdoptedOpenJDK** or **Amazon Corretto**.

1. **Amazon Corretto 8 Download** : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-8-ug/downloads-list.html (Free and open to use)
2. **AdoptedOpenJDK Download** : https://adoptopenjdk.net/ (Free and open to use)

**Note :** I personally like **Amazon Corretto** as while installing, it sets the java in the classpath automatically. You don't need to manually set it.

Useful Resources :

1. [Difference between OpenJDK and AdoptOpenJDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52431764/difference-between-openjdk-and-adoptopenjdk)