# Error in installing Java - Bad CPU type in executable

Tags: java, macos, apple-m1

I have a new Macbook Pro M1 Chip, 2020. OS Version is `Big Sir 11.4`. I tried installing `Java OpenJDK 16`. These are the instructions I followed . https://knasmueller.net/how-to-install-java-openjdk-16-on-macos-big-sur

when I executed `java -version` this is the error I get.

```
exec failed: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=86 "Bad CPU type in executable" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Failed to execute /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-16.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java: Bad CPU type in executable}
```

Why is this and how to fix it?

Comment: You probably need a specific version for the M1 processor architecture. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64788005/java-jdk-for-apple-m1-chip and not the usual x86-64 version for Intel processors

Comment: @JohannesB: That is something unexpected... What is AdpotOpenJDK???

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52431764/difference-between-openjdk-and-adoptium-adoptopenjdk

Comment: @JohannesB: At `Azul`, what is the architecture name for M1 Chip? Is it ARM 64 Bit?

Comment: @PeakGen - read https://www.macrumors.com/guide/m1/

Comment: AArch64 or ARM64 is the generic family name the M1 processor belongs to.