# why eclipse-temurin official did not have OpenJ9 docker image

Tags: docker

Because OpenJ9 could save 30% memory usage, I use OpenJ9 in my project. Now the AdoptJDKOfficial docker image [did not maintain in the furture](https://hub.docker.com/_/adoptopenjdk). Today I tried to migration my project from AdoptJDK docker image to eclipse-temurin, but I did not found any docker image about OpenJ9. I am seaching from internet and somebody told that the license problem, is there possible to use OpenJ9 in the furture? why did not support OpenJ9 in the
[eclipse-temurin](https://hub.docker.com/_/eclipse-temurin/) official? I search from internet but did found any explain about this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TLDR:** Look for [Semeru](https://developer.ibm.com/languages/java/semeru-runtimes/) instead of Temurin.

As you can see on the [AdoptOpenJDK blog](https://blog.adoptopenjdk.net/2021/08/goodbye-adoptopenjdk-hello-adoptium/)

```
OpenJ9 builds

Part of Eclipse’s agreement governing the use of the Oracle Java SE TCK,
requires that Adoptium does not release OpenJ9-based or GraalVM-based
runtimes. We know that OpenJ9 builds were very popular at AdoptOpenJDK,
and we are delighted to report that IBM has stepped in to provide
equivalent builds directly from their website.

Adoptium has plans to distribute multiple vendor builds of OpenJDK
in the near future, so keep an eye on the Adoptium blog site for more
information about that exciting adventure.
```

So what you are looking for isn't a temurin docker immage, but a semeru docker image. [Semeru](https://developer.ibm.com/languages/java/semeru-runtimes/) being the name of IBM's equivalent to Temurin with OpenJ9 (the version the AdoptOpenJDK blog talked about).

Both can be installed/managed e.g. via [SDKMAN](https://sdkman.io/).